# Retrieve Multiple Child branches Firebase Swift 4 in TableView

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database, tableview, crud

The real-time database structure of firebase is as follows:
[image]

Then, I intend to show the values for each of the children in several table view as shown below

[image]

In my table view I only receive individual fields and not the data array that I intend to show, that is, I only get the values of **ShowDataOne** and not the other fields as shown in my JSON

```
 { "CrudPrincipal" : {
"-LeCyGwSM-Ozsf8MmADa" : {
  "Clasification" : "fsdfsdf",
  "Name" : "fsdfsdf",
  "Uses" : "fdsfsd"
},
"-LeDVuUxNKM-IzqmWb3s" : {
  "Clasification" : "fdsfnj",
  "Name" : "hOdw",
  "Uses" : "fjdjf"
},
"-LeMqN4MfJYl1_ef-Umy" : {
  "Clasification" : "Vázquez",
  "Name" : "Daniel",
  "Uses" : "fdjnfjd"
},
"-LeMrCIEvwRrz8YWwbnS" : {
  "Clasification" : "erf3",
  "Name" : "frf3q",
  "Uses" : "rf3"
},
"-LeMs5uFRP21y8KMOwPo" : {
  "Clasification" : "fases",
  "Name" : "dadas",
  "Uses" : "gfdgdfoigj"
},
"ShowDataOne" : "Hello World, first Data!"
},
```

My code for the data model is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class oneCrudClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameFieldOne: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var clasificationFieldOne: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usesFieldOne: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var postDataRef = [String]()
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        // Set firebase reference
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        // Retrieve the data and listen for changes
        databaseHandle = ref.child("CrudPrincipal").observe(.childAdded, with:  { (DataSnapshot) in
            let crudOne = DataSnapshot.value as? String
            if let actualInfo = crudOne {
                self.postDataRef.append(actualInfo)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postDataRef.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "PostCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = postDataRef[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            postDataRef.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func posData(_ sender: Any) {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        if nameFieldOne.text != "" && clasificationFieldOne.text != "" && usesFieldOne.text != "" {
            self.ref?.child("CrudPrincipal").childByAutoId().setValue(["Name": nameFieldOne.text, "Clasification": clasificationFieldOne.text, "Uses": usesFieldOne.text])
            nameFieldOne.text = ""
            clasificationFieldOne.text = ""
            usesFieldOne.text = ""
        } else {
            print("Missing fields")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because other values are not String

```
let crudOne = DataSnapshot.value as? String
            if let actualInfo = crudOne {
                self.postDataRef.append(actualInfo)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

change this to be able to parse Dictionary:

```
"-LeMs5uFRP21y8KMOwPo" : {
  "Clasification" : "fases",
  "Name" : "dadas",
  "Uses" : "gfdgdfoigj"
}
```

+++Addition:
On the receiver side, you have DataSnapshot, which can contain Any data type, and you are using DataSnapshot.value as? String assuming that this value would be a String. And if not,

> self.postDataRef.append(actualInfo) and self.tableView.reloadData()

will not be executed.
This data like:

> "-LeMs5uFRP21y8KMOwPo" : {...

is not a String, but Dictionary Object. So you have to check it if it is a String -> just add like now, but if not you must call

> DataSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value as? String

(in your case of course) to get children value.

```
let crudOne = DataSnapshot.value as? String
                if let actualInfo = crudOne {
                    self.postDataRef.append(actualInfo)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                } else if let actualInfo = DataSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value as? String {
                    self.postDataRef.append(actualInfo)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

something like this

Comment: Hi, could you be a little more descriptive of if I have to delete the CrudPrincipal branch? In any case I would have to change self.ref? .Child ("CrudPrincipal") by self.ref? .ChildByAutoID ()

Comment: Hi, please check my edited answer it is more clearly explaining what is happening in your code. Also, you can use print("Test message") to debug how does the code execute and find an issue.

Comment: Now I get the data with name value :D
You already gave me the solution for the other values, thanks bro